# rowstack not stacking in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I was trying to learn some histograms tools in gnuplot, I made the following script

```
set samples 500

set table "set1.dat"
plot [0:10] 5+2*rand(0)
unset table
set table "set2.dat"
plot [0:10] 10*rand(0)
unset table

rmin  = 0.0
rmax  = 10.0
nbins = 20.0
binwidth = (rmax-rmin)/nbins
bin(x,w) = w*(floor((x-rmin)/w)+0.5)+rmin

set table "h1.dat"
plot "set1.dat" u (bin($2,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes noti
unset table
set table "h2.dat"
plot "set2.dat" u (bin($2,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes noti
unset table
```

I want to plot the histograms h1 and h2 on top of each other (`rowstack`). It should be noted at that point, that `h1.dat` and `h2.dat` have a last line marked `u` (instead of `i`), which somehow appears to screw the plot. I then tried the following

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstack
set boxwidth 0.9*binwidth

plot "< grep i h2.dat" u 1:2 w boxes noti, "< grep i h1.dat" u 1:2 w boxes noti
```

Which gives me

[image: Overlapping histograms]

Individually, the two histograms are fine. But they hardly follow the `rowstack`-stacking approach. I tried replacing the `u 1:2` by `u 2` as all examples around seem to be using that. But then the bins are placed on every units instead of every half units. Which I suppose, I could solve by using `u 2:xtic(1)`. But in any case the second (red) histogram is moved down the the left side of the spectrum.

My question is then quite simple: **why doesn't the second histogram stack on top of the first one?**

Comment: `with boxes` draws boxes, `with histrogram` draws histograms.

Comment: @Christoph indeed. However I can't have `u 1:2 w histograms` as it complains about too many columns. And if I have `u 2 w histograms`, the second do stand on the top of the first. But the bins are still on each units and not half units. And the second one gets moved to the lower part of the spectrum (left). So that it starts from 0 instead of starting from 5.

Comment: Yes, I see. When plotting histograms, gnuplot doesn't have a numerical x-axis, but implicitely uses integer numbers starting at 0, and you can only change the xticlabel. So, for the values to stack properly, you must have data files with equal x-values, which gnuplot, however, doesn't generate if the x values are in different ranges. Gnuplot isn't a data processing tool. Your best option would be to use an external script (in Python, awk, perl, whatever) to generate properly binned data which you can then stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need external tools or scripts for this task.
You simply need a few extra lines in gnuplot.

If the x-ranges of your two histograms are not the same, you simply have to make them the same, but how?
Since gnuplot 5.0 you can print to datablocks via `with table`. With this you can simply append datablocks.
So, append `$Histo1` and `$Histo2` into a  new table `$Histo3`. Apply `smooth freq` on `$Histo3` and you will get the sum of `$Histo1` and `$Histo2` in `$Histo4`.

Now, you plot `$Histo4` with the color you want for `$Histo1` and afterwards `$Histo2` on top.
Unless you want transparent boxes you can use this to "mimic" a stacked histogram.
You can do the same "trick" for impulses: [How to stack impulses in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67064995/7295599)

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 5.0.0, Jan 2015)

```
### stack histograms with different x-ranges
reset session

# create some random test data
set samples 500
set table $Data1
    plot [0:10] 5+2*rand(0)
set table $Data2
    plot [0:10] 10*rand(0)
unset table

rmin  = 0.0
rmax  = 10.0
nbins = 20.0
binwidth = (rmax-rmin)/nbins
bin(x,w) = w*(floor((x-rmin)/w)+0.5)+rmin

set table $Histo1
    plot $Data1 u (bin($2,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq
set table $Histo2
    plot $Data2 u (bin($2,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq
unset table

set table $Histo3
    plot $Histo1 u 1:2 w table
    plot $Histo2 u 1:2 w table
set table $Histo4
    plot $Histo3 u 1:2 smooth freq
unset table

# set offsets 0,0,0,0
set yrange [0:]
set key out
set grid y
set boxwidth 0.8 relative    # for gnuplot<5.0.7 you should use: set boxwidth 0.4 absolute
set style fill solid 0.3

set multiplot layout 3,1

    set ytics 40
    plot $Histo1 u 1:2 w boxes lc "red" ti "Data1"

    set ytics 10
    plot $Histo2 u 1:2 w boxes lc "blue" ti "Data2"

    set ytics 40
    plot $Histo4 u 1:2 w boxes lc "red"  ti "Data1", \
         $Histo2 u 1:2 w boxes lc "blue" ti "Data2"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I did not test it on the version I had back then, but it works with Gnuplot 5.4, thank you!