# How to stack impulses in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot to show the precipitation measured during the last 13 monthts. Data is read from two data files, rain.dat and snow.dat. I use impulses, but on days with both rain and snow the impulses are plotted over each other. It had been better if the impulses were stacked.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d.%m.%Y"
set ylabel "Precipitation (mm)"
set xrange ["01.`date --date="1 year ago" +%m.%Y`":"01`date --date="1 month" +.%m.%Y`"]
set xtics "01.`date --date="1 year ago" +%m.%Y`",2800000, \
          "01.`date --date="now 1 month" +%m.%Y`" offset 3,0.2
set format x "%b"
set style line 100 lt 3 lc rgb "gray" lw 0.5
set style line 101 lt 3 lc rgb "gray" lw 0.5
set grid back xtics ytics mytics ls 100, ls 100, ls 101
set terminal png size 1000,200
set output 'precipitation.png'
plot 'rain.dat' using 1:2 title 'Rain' w impulses lt rgb '#ff0000' lw 4 , \
     'snow.dat' using 1:2 title 'Snow' w impulses lt rgb '#0000ff' lw 2

rain.dat:
16.02.2021 8
22.02.2021 6
04.03.2021 10
08.03.2021 13
14.03.2021 5

snow.dat:
19.02.2021 19
22.02.2021 10
04.03.2021 14
12.03.2021 8
```

[image]

How can impulses be stacked with Gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ethan already mentioned, `with impulses` will always start at `0`. If you don't mind some little extra effort, you can mimic "stacking" impulses if you first plot the sum of rain and snow with the "snow color", and then plot rain alone with the "rain color" on top of it.

But how do you get the sum of rain and snow?

- plot your datablocks (or files) into the temporary datablock `$Temp`.
- plot datablock `$Temp` into the datablock `$SnowAndRain` using the option `smooth frequency` which sums up snow and rain for each day. Check `help smooth`.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.2.0, Sept. 2017)

```
### "stacked" impulses
reset session

$Rain <<EOD
16.02.2021 8
22.02.2021 6
04.03.2021 10
08.03.2021 13
14.03.2021 5
EOD

$Snow <<EOD
19.02.2021 19
22.02.2021 10
04.03.2021 14
12.03.2021 8
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y"

set table $Temp
    plot $Snow u (sprintf("%.0f",timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt))):2 w table
    plot $Rain u (sprintf("%.0f",timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt))):2 w table
set table $SnowAndRain
    set format x "%.0f"
    plot $Temp u 1:2 smooth freq
unset table

set format x "%d %b" timedate
plot $SnowAndRain u 1:2 w impulses lw 4 lc "blue" title 'Snow', \
            $Rain u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w impulses lc "red" lw 4 title 'Rain', \
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

A bit more cumbersome solution which seem to work with gnuplot 5.0.0 (at least with Win10). I hope somebody can simplify this.

**Script:** (tested with Win10 gnuplot 5.0.0. Same result as above)

```
### "stacked" impulses (should work with gnuplot 5.0.0)
reset session

$Rain <<EOD
16.02.2021 8
22.02.2021 6
04.03.2021 10
08.03.2021 13
14.03.2021 5
EOD

$Snow <<EOD
19.02.2021 19
22.02.2021 10
04.03.2021 14
12.03.2021 8
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y"

set table $Temp
    plot $Snow u (t=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)/1e5,int(t)):2:((t-int(t))*1e5) w table
    plot $Rain u (t=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)/1e5,int(t)):2:((t-int(t))*1e5) w table
unset table

set table $SnowAndRain
    set format x "%.0f"
    plot $Temp u ($1*1e5+$3):2 smooth freq
unset table

set format x "%d %b" timedate 
plot $SnowAndRain u 1:2 w impulses lw 4 lc "blue" title 'Snow', \
            $Rain u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w impulses lc "red" lw 4 title 'Rain'
### end of script
```

Comment: In Windows 10 the output is correct, but in Raspbian Stretch and Gnuplot 5.0 the graph is totally wrong. I get "Warning: empty x range [-6.2041e+10:-6.2041e+10], adjusting to [-6.26614e+10:-6.14206e+10]". The first line of table $Temp is "1.61369e+09 19".There is obviously a problem with the time format in Linux.

Comment: @EddySorngard ok, tested with Win10 and gnuplot 5.2.0 and it works. However, Win10 and gnuplot 5.0.0 to 5.0.6 give wrong results. Right now, I don't know what it is. So, probably, no specific Linux problem, but a gnuplot version issue. I will try to find out.

Comment: The addition works in Linux too, But if I try to extend the plot to 13 months as I used to do, adding  **set xrange ["01.`date --date="1 year ago" +%m.%Y`":"01`date --date="1 month" +.%m.%Y`"]**   before  **set format x "%d %b" timedate** , i get "Can't plot with an empty x range!"

Comment: @EddySorngard this `date --date="1 year ago" +%m.%Y` doesn't exist in Windows. And I'm not sure whether it works this way in gnuplot under Linux. If you want to set the range to the last year from now (well, last 365 days + 30 next days), for the Addition, I would use the gnuplot commands: `now=time(0); set xrange[now-3600*24*365:now+3600*24*30]`. Check `help time`. If you need exactly 1 year minus and until the end of the current month, there is a more complicated gnuplot solution.

Comment: this works in Linux and Gnuplot 5.0 too. But how to make the x-axis look like the figure in my original question, only with the name of the months? Or is it possible to get "1. Mar" instead of "01 Mar"?

Comment: @EddySorngard check `help time_specifiers`.

Answer (score 1):

Impulses cannot be stacked.  By definition they extend from y=0 to some non-zero y value.

If the two data sets were sampled at the same set of x coordinates then you could use the stacked histogram plot mode, but that isn't the case here.

How about back-to-back impulses rather than stacked impulses?

```
$RAIN << EOD
16.02.2021 8
22.02.2021 6
04.03.2021 10
08.03.2021 13
14.03.2021 5
EOD

$SNOW << EOD
19.02.2021 19
22.02.2021 10
04.03.2021 14
12.03.2021 8
EOD

set xzeroaxis

plot $RAIN using 1:2 with impulse lw 3, \
     $SNOW using 1:(-$2) with impulse lw 3
```

[image]

Comment: This does not show the total amount of precipitation per day. Maybe I can use histogram if data for both rain and snow are written to one file instead of separate files?

Comment: Merging the data sets into a single file would help only if the format is something like `date rain snow`. That way there are both rain and snow entries for every date (x coordinate).  The problem as it is now is that the two data sets do not have the same set of x coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make a simplification to @theozh's answer, but some of the pulses are slightly displaced in time. @theozh has a much better solution of my problem.

```
reset session

$Rain <<EOD
16.02.2021 8
22.02.2021 6
04.03.2021 10
08.03.2021 13
14.03.2021 5
EOD

$Snow <<EOD
19.02.2021 19
22.02.2021 10
04.03.2021 14
12.03.2021 8
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y"

set table $Temp
    plot $Snow u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w table
    plot $Rain u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w table
unset table

set table $SnowAndRain
     plot $Temp u 1:2 smooth freq
unset table

set format x "%d %b" timedate
plot $SnowAndRain u 1:2 w impulses lw 4 lc "blue" title 'Snow', \
     $Rain u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w impulses lc "red" lw 4 title 'Rain', \
### end of code
```

**Addition:**

The rain and snow pulses are drawn on top of each other if $Rain is written to table $RainTemp using (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 before plotting the the graph. But still the timing is bit incorrect.

```
reset session

$Rain <<EOD
16.02.2021 8
22.02.2021 6
04.03.2021 10
08.03.2021 13
14.03.2021 5
EOD

$Snow <<EOD
19.02.2021 19
22.02.2021 10
04.03.2021 14
12.03.2021 8
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y"

set table $Temp
    plot $Snow u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w table
    plot $Rain u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w table
unset table

set table $SnowAndRain
     plot $Temp u 1:2 smooth freq
unset table

set table $RainTemp
    plot $Rain u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w table
unset table

set format x "%d %b" timedate
plot $SnowAndRain u 1:2 w impulses lw 4 lc "blue" title 'Snow', \
     $RainTemp u 1:2 w impulses lw 4 lc "red" title 'Rain'
```

Comment: Are you sure? Why do you think `smooth` would not accept floating point numbers?

Comment: @theozh, My mistake, convertion to integer in smoth is not necessay. Then the simplification is even simpler.

Comment: I had this version and I was not satisfied.Have you zoomed in (e.g. in wxt terminal)? If you zoom-in very close you will notice that in some cases the red and the blue impulses are not exactly on top of each other. That`s why I came up with the more complicated addition in my answer.

Comment: @theozh, I did not notice that, but now I see it. The solution was too simple. I will detete my answer.

Comment: @theozh, Now I have added a better solution.

Comment: well, almost. With your latest change, the impulses are now top of each other, 
however, if you again zoom in, for example Feb 22 00:00 becomes Feb 21 23:27. This is because the dates are written as floating point number with only 6 digits of precision (standard format "%g") into the table. This can lead to an error as large as a few 1000 seconds. It's a detail but strictly speaking not correct.

Comment: @theozh, I see. So you can not write a floaing pont number with a higher precition than 6 digits to $Temp, therefore you has to wrtite the last digits in column 3.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's it what is going on (at least in gnuplot 5.0.). My first version is working from gnuplot 5.2.0 on..., but I guess for 5.0 you need this strange workaround of my second version (at least, so far, I haven't found another solution for 5.0).

Comment: @theozh, thank you, I have learned a lot from this discussion..